# How do I shuffle a deck? How do I make a string array constructor?

Tags: java, arrays

Thank you for everyone's help!! This is what I went with.

### 3/30/2011-

> import java.util.Arrays; public class
>   Deck {
>
> ```
> String [] cards = {"AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H",
> ```
>
> "9H", "10H", "JH", "QH", "KH",
>                       "AC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C",
>   "10C", "JC", "QC", "KC",
>                       "AD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D",
>   "10D", "JD", "QD", "KD",
>                       "AS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S",
>   "10S", "JS", "QS", "KS",
>       };
>
> ```
> Deck(){
>
> }
>
>
> public void shuffle()
> {
>     String [] temp = new String[52];
>     for ( int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
>         temp [2*i] = cards[i];
>         temp [2*i+1]= cards[i+26];
>      }
>
>     cards = temp;
>
>  }
>
>
>
> @Override
> public String toString() {
>
>     String cards1 = "";
>     for ( int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
>         cards1 += cards[i] + " ";
>         if ((i+1)%13==0){
>             cards1 += "\n";
>         }
>     }
>                 return cards1;
>
> }
>
>
> public boolean equals(Deck other) {
>         for (int i=0; i<cards.length; ++i) {
>             if (!this.cards[i].equals(other.cards[i]))
> ```
>
> return false;
>               }
>           return true;
>       }
>
> }

Hi, I need some assistance with my lab hw.

B. It is said that if a deck of cards is given perfect shuffles enough times, it will return to its original order. A perfect shuffle is done by splitting the deck exactly in half and interleaving the cards from the two halves; that is, the first card is from the first half, the second from the second half, the third from the first half and so on.

I need to include the following methods.
-Deck() constructor that creates an unshuffled deck.
-A shuffle() method that does a perfect shuffle.
-A toString() method that print the deck
-An equals(Deck aDeck) method that compares itself with he given deck and returns true if all the cards in both decks are in the same order and false otherwise

I think I am having problems with the constructor part. I don't know how to create a correct constructor for string arrays.  I have three java books, and none of them touched on it.

> public class DeckTester {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @param args the command line arguments
>  */
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     Deck d1 = new Deck();
>
>     System.out.println(d1);
>
>     }
> }      public class Deck {
>
> String [] cards = {"AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H",
> ```
>
> "9H", "10H", "JH", "QH", "KH",
>                          "AC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C",
>   "9C", "10C", "JC", "QC", "KC",
>                          "AD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D",
>   "9D", "10D", "JD", "QD", "KD",
>                          "AS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S",
>   "9S", "10S", "JS", "QS", "KS",
>       };
>
> Deck(){ 
>           cards = new String []{};    }
>
> ```
>      public void shuffle()
>      {
>      for ( int i = 0; i< cards.length; i++){
>          String temp = cards[ i ]; // swap
>          cards[ i ] = cards[ i+25 ]; // the
>          cards[ i+25 ] = temp; // cards
>      }
>  }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: everybody else had two separate arrays, one for the suits and one for the numbers...but he wants us to do it this way...

Comment: You don't need to initialize your cards element again in the Deck constructor, it's already been initialized by your assignment above it.... what problem are you having?

Comment: How do I create an object with those values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could assume that the cards will always be the same. So you could have a constant that defines the set of cards available.

Your constructor then simply allocates memory and copies the constant array to this member variable.

```
public class Deck {
  // static final defines a constant valid for all the objects of that class.
  // this will allow us to initiase our array in a clean way.
  // You will notice that constants are always named with capital letters. 
  private static final String[] ORDERED_CARDS = new String[] {
      "AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H",
      "9H", "10H", "JH"
      // etc.
    };

  // This is the member variable that holds the cards for our Deck objects
  private String[] cards;

  // The constructor allocates memory with the new keyword
  // Then it uses a function from the Java library to copy from one array to the other
  public Deck() {
    cards = new String[ORDERED_CARDS.length];
    System.arraycopy(ORDERED_CARDS, 0, cards, 0, ORDERED_CARDS.length);
  }

  // Using Google "java shuffle array" you'll find how to do it in one line using the 
  // Java library. There are other ways to do it, depending on which shuffle type 
  // you need. You could as well implement your own algorithm. The class to generate 
  // random numbers is called Random (part of the Java library)
  public void shuffle() {
    assert(cards!=null);
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cards));
  }

  // The toString method shows how to iterate over an array or a collection using the 
  // "for-each" loop. We use a StringBuffer to build a string with the resulting card 
  // list. The final keyword says that this variable will not be re-allocated anywhere
  // else during this method. This avoids mistakes in long methods and also allows the
  // Java compiler to optimize your code
  public String toString() {
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (String card : cards) {
      sb.append(card);
      sb.append(", ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  // The equals method shows how to iterate over an array or a collection using the 
  // "for" loop. 
  public boolean equals(Deck other) {
    if (other==null) return false;

    // assert is used to ensure that a Deck will always have cards. If not, the program 
    // will throw an Exception. This is good practise when you write classes to assert 
    // that you don't get values that should not be possible.
    assert(other.cards!=null);

    // Decks can only be equal if they have the same number of cards
    if (other.cards.length != this.cards.length) return false;

    final int cardCount = this.cards.length;
    for (int i=0; i<cardCount; ++i) {
      // Always compare strings using the equals method, not ==
      if (!this.cards[i].equals(other.cards[i])) return false;
    }

    // If we reach this point, then we have equal objects
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i haven't learn most of the stuff you used :), it is a little advance for me lol

Comment: I have added comments to help you understand what I did.

Comment: You're missing [] on the declaration of your constant.

Comment: Hi, how come it I received this error code? incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String[]
required: java.lang.String
  private static final String ORDERED_CARDS = new String[] {

Comment: nvm wds found it, and what package do I need to import over to use arraycopy?

Comment: annot find symbol
symbol  : variable Arrays
location: class Deck
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cards));
 cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Collections
location: class Deck
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cards));

Comment: that's my last question for now..I am going to reread the array chapter again.

Comment: You either let Eclipse do it for you (use CTRL + SHIFT + O shorcut or right click > Organize imports). Or you look for the Arrays class in the Java documentation (use Google). This will tell you the package it is contained in.

Comment: Bookmark this link: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html This will give you all the documentation you need about the Java library classes.

Comment: +1: You have good explainations but the code is much more complicated than it needs to be IMHO. Most methods should be just one line.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I don't believe in making the code any more complicated than it needs to be.

```
public class Deck {
    private final String[] cards = "AH,2H,3H,4H,5H,6H,7H,8H,9H,10H,JH,QH,KH,AC,2C,3C,4C,5C,6C,7C,8C,9C,10C,JC,QC,KC,AD,2D,3D,4D,5D,6D,7D,8D,9D,10D,JD,QD,KD,AS,2S,3S,4S,5S,6S,7S,8S,9S,10S,JS,QS,KS".split(",");
    // the default constructor will do everything, nothing needs to be added.

    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cards));
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(cards);
    }

    // equals must extend equals(Object) or it won't do what you thing.
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return other instanceof Deck 
            && Arrays.equals(cards, ((Deck) other).cards);
    }
}
```

Comment: But you're not declaring it in the constructor now.

Comment: @Roflcopter, There is no need for the constructor.

Comment: I dont think so too, but in the questions it is mentioned: 'Deck() constructor that creates an unshuffled deck'

Comment: Hm, I still don't understand it clearly, do you guys know any sites that directly addresses this? or is pretty similar to it?

Comment: The default constructor still would. ;)

Comment: Coding a simple constructor/initialising a field should be covered by any book/site on how to learn Java. You may be better off asking specific questions.

Comment: Yes it would but not directly in the constructor ;)

Answer (score 1):

This does what I believe you want. I left out the shuffling part to not give the whole answer away :)

```
public class Deck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        System.out.println(deck);

        String original = deck.toString();
        while (true) {
            deck.shuffle();
            System.out.println(deck);
            if (deck.toString().equals(original)) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    String[] cards = { "AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H",
            "10H", "JH", "QH", "KH", "AC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C",
            "8C", "9C", "10C", "JC", "QC", "KC", "AD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D",
            "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "10D", "JD", "QD", "KD", "AS", "2S", "3S",
            "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "10S", "JS", "QS", "KS", };

    public void shuffle() {
        // omitted
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String card : cards) {
            builder.append(card + " ");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're constructor should look like this:

```
public class Deck {

private String[] cards = new String[52];

       public Deck() {
         cards[0] = "AH";
         cards[1] = "2H";
         cards[2] = "3H";
         cards[3] = "4H";
         cards[4] = "5H";
         cards[5] = "6H";

            //and so on

       }
    }
```

Comment: You're constructing a local cards variable here, that's hiding the class member, so when the constructor completes, the class members cards element won't have changed.

Comment: It might help if the constructor initialises a class attribute instead of a variable with limited scope :-)

Comment: Ah ok now I understand what he wants.. Thanks

Comment: But how do I use the instance variable?

Comment: I think `cards` needs to be a field. ;)

Comment: He didn't have it in a field though.

Comment: I see how it is much easier if it was in a field, but how do I do it if it wasn't?

Comment: It would be easier if it wasn't a field but just a variable with local scope

Comment: It can be declared in one line. Nnot sure what you gain having 53 lines. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey yes but in your answer you're not declaring it in the constructor.

Comment: hm, so this way, I can create an instance of the class by writing Deck deck1 = new deck();? and it will have all the data inside the arrays?