# Not sure how to make this deck shuffle

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
import java.util.*;

public class shuffleDeck
{ 
  public static int shuffleDeck (int[] deck, int theNumber) 
  {
     int [] deck2 = new int [26];
     int [] deck3 = new int [26];
     return theNumber;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int [] deck = new int [52];
    for(int i=0; i<52; i++)
    {
        deck[i]=i+1;
    }
    int count;
    count=1;
    int total=1;
    shuffleDeck(deck, count);
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

I have been trying to make this deck shuffle for the past hour no with no luck. I split the deck in half and was going to shuffle the array count the amount of times it shuffles and then print out the array after its been shuffled.    I'm not sure at all actually how to add the third array that would shuffle them all. But if anyone knows if you could mind telling me that'd be great.

Comment: Do you mean an array that suffle deck, deck2 and deck3?

Comment: Why are you splitting the deck in half? It's not clear what that achieves... See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle for a good shuffling algorithm.

Comment: Yes i am trying to shuffle all decks

Comment: What do you mean by "all decks"? Surely you have a *single* deck of 52 cards...

Comment: But again, you're starting with *one* array. You still haven't explained why you're creating two smaller arrays to start with...

Comment: Have you tried searching for "shuffle deck" in stackoverflow ? Or even simpler, have you taken a look at the right side of the screen in "Related" section ? It has been already asked many many times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I shuffle a deck? How do I make a string array constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430170/how-do-i-shuffle-a-deck-how-do-i-make-a-string-array-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you split the deck in half, but if you dont need to, then you could use `Collections.shuffle()`:

```
// Create an array, fill it the way you want
Integer[] deck = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4};

// Shuffle the elements in the array
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(deck));
```

Comment: Not the correct answer anymore? What happened, need more help? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void shuffle(int[] deck) {
    // the random number generator used to shuffle the deck
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = deck.length, j, tmp; i > 1; i--) {
        // get a random position between 0 and i-1
        j = random.nextInt(i); 
        // swap the current position (i-1) with the random one ...
        tmp = deck[i - 1];
        deck[i - 1] = deck[j];
        deck[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just plopping down code probably isn't much help for the OP.  At the very least, put comments in your code explaining how it works to the OP.  And it would improve your answer even more if you included text describing why the OP's code won't work.

Comment: sorry, I taught it's pretty self explanatory