# ERROR: This method must return a result of type int

Tags: java

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class shuffleDeck
{ 
    public static int shuffleDeck (int[] deck, int theNumber)
    {
        int [] array1 = new int [52];

        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = deck.length, j, tmp; i > 1; i--) {
            j = random.nextInt(i);

            tmp = deck[i - 1];
            deck[i - 1] = deck[j];
            deck[j] = tmp;
            return theNumber;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [] deck = new int [52];
        for(int i=0; i<52; i++)
        {
            deck[i]=i+1;
        }
        int count;
        count=1;
        int total=1;
        shuffleDeck(deck, count);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

There is an error on the method shuffleDeck. I am not sure what it means I need to return something but it wont return and I am getting this odd error.

I have not been able to solve this I have looked around all over stack. 
Thank you to whoever can help me fix this error.

Comment: class name and the method name can't be same. It becomes a constructor.

Comment: Why do you have a loop if you return from the method on the first iteration of the loop?  Why have any code at all if you just return the value you're given, unmodified?  And at that point... Why even return anything?  The calling code already has that value.

Comment: You're also returning the un-altered value of the `theNumber` argument, is that intentional? That's also somewhat related to your problem: `theNumber` is a plain old `int`, not an `int[]`, so it isn't compatible with your declared return type of `int[]`.

Comment: Please stick to the Java naming conventions (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). This would possible have prevented your error

Answer (score 2):

On java, when you define a method, that method must either must return a value, or must be declared with the void keyword.

```
public static int shuffleDeck(int[] deck);
```

means, you are going to return a primitive integer (***int***) with the use of ***return*** keyword.

```
public static int shuffleDeck(int[] deck);
```

means, you are not going to return something, thus ***void*** is used here to declare that.

Finally, I think this is what you try to accomplish, there were some several problems on the code you have provided, may be you can go over the sample below;

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test1 {

    public static void shuffleDeck(int[] deck) {
        int[] array1 = new int[52];

        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = deck.length, j, tmp; i > 1; i--) {
            j = random.nextInt(i);

            tmp = deck[i - 1];
            deck[i - 1] = deck[j];
            deck[j] = tmp;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] deck = new int[52];
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
            deck[i] = i + 1;
        }

        System.out.println("Initial Ordered Deck");
        printDeck(deck);

        int count;
        count = 1;
        int total = 1;

        shuffleDeck(deck);

        System.out.println("Shuffled Deck");
        printDeck(deck);

    }

    private static void printDeck(int[] deck) {
        System.out.println("**************************************");

        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
            if (i % 13 == 0 && i > 0 )
                System.out.println();

            System.out.printf("%2d ", deck[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("\n**************************************");
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

And the output is;

```
Initial Ordered Deck
**************************************
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 
14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 
**************************************

Shuffled Deck
**************************************
22  6 13 11 35 23 29 27  8 30 44 20  1 
31 34 28 47  5 46 17 51 38  3 19 36 18 
42 33  7  4  2 24 41  9 15 45 21 16 37 
14 48 43 49 32 12 40 39 26 50 52 10 25 
**************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
public static int shuffleDeck (int[] deck, int theNumber)
```

to

```
public static void shuffleDeck (int[] deck, int theNumber)
```

if you define a `return type` you have to deliver one.
`void` defines that no return type is needed.
In this case remove:

```
return theNumber;
```

inside the `shuffleDeck` method.

Comment: `theNumber` is not changed at all. I believe that's not what the OP wants. changing the return type to `void` should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have declared return type as int and you have given return statment inside for loop now think what will happen if your code dont go in for loop than there will be no return statement so,

so make your code like

```
public static int shuffleDeck (int[] deck, int theNumber)
  {
 int [] array1 = new int [52];    
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = deck.length, j, tmp; i > 1; i--) {
        j = random.nextInt(i);    
        tmp = deck[i - 1];
        deck[i - 1] = deck[j];
        deck[j] = tmp;
        return theNumber;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uppercase the name of your class to distinguish between class and method:

```
public class ShuffleDeck {
...
```

Perhaps it is even better to rename the method:

```
public static int doTheShuffle(int[] deck, int theNumber) {
```

If you want the function to return something sensible put the return out of the loop:

```
for (int i = deck.length, j, tmp; i > 1; i--) {
    j = random.nextInt(i);

    tmp = deck[i - 1];
    deck[i - 1] = deck[j];
    deck[j] = tmp;
}

return theNumber;
```

But all of this will only make the compiler not complain about syntax errors. **Your algorithm still has bugs**.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your main method, I suppose, that what you want is to shuffle the deck for the given `count` of times, for that you should update the method as follows:

```
public static void shuffleDeck (int[] deck, int theNumber)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int k=0; k < theNumber; k++) {
        for (int i = deck.length, j, tmp; i > 1; i--) {
            j = random.nextInt(i);

            tmp = deck[i - 1];
            deck[i - 1] = deck[j];
            deck[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

for returning the number of how many times you actually did the shuffle doesn't make sense ... based on your input. The inner loop, as posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757452/4234940 is only the shuffle itself... so actually I would change it like this:

```
public static void shuffleDeck (int[] deck, int theNumber)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int k=0; k < theNumber; k++) {
        shuffle(deck, random);
    }
}

private static void shuffle(int[] array, Random random){
    for (int i = array.length, j, tmp; i > 1; i--) {
        j = random.nextInt(i);

        tmp = array[i - 1];
        array[i - 1] = array[j];
        array[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```